# How to use GNU extension like wc as execvp's argument in clion?

Tags: c, clion

Simple segment:

```
//temp.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *myargs[3];
    myargs[0] = strdup("wc");
    myargs[1] = strdup("temp.c");
    myargs[2] = NULL;
    execvp(myargs[0], myargs);
}
```

In terminal:

> $ gcc temp.c; ./a.out
>   hello, I am child (pid:30232)
>   17  37 362 temp.c

Ok, it works fine.

In clion:

> wc: temp.c: No such file or directory

So, how can i enable gnu extension like `wc` in clion?

Comment: the error message indicates that wc is found and executed but not in the source directory where temp.c is.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt so how can i fix it?

Comment: I don't know clion so I can't answer that. Check if you can set the runtime directory of programs executed

Comment: *so how can i fix it?*  Umm, why did you type the `./` part of `./a.out ...` in your command line version? (Yes, there's a relation to your question)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thank you for your inspiration.

Comment: Your program successfully runs `wc`; the error message is being produced by `wc`. It tells you what the problem is, too.

Comment: By the way, it is unnecessary to `strdup` literal strings just to pass them to `execvp`.  `execvp` does not modify the contents of the `argv` array it is passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLion compiles and runs your program in a separate build directory specified in CMake project settings, usually it's a `cmake-build-debug` subdirectory in your project root. This means, there's no `temp.c` file in the working directory when you run your program.

In other words, your project layout most likely looks like:

```
.
├── cmake-build-debug
│   ├── temp  ### <- your executable
│   └── ...
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── temp.c
```

Try passing an absolute path to `/path/to/temp.c`, or a relative path to find it from the working directory, which is the project build directory, that is, `../temp.c`.